# How to force session timeout for idle users in UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication?

Tags: c#, .net, owin, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I am using UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication for my application. But the session timeout is occurring even for a user actively working on the application, after 1 hour.
Is there a way to force timeout only for users who are idle. And also is there a way to specify time when session timeout should happen?

```
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        // Configure Cookie-based Authentication
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions() { SlidingExpiration = true, });

new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {

                ClientId = <some value>,
                Authority = authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutUrl,
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        context.HandleResponse();
                        context.Response.Redirect("/Error?message=" + context.Exception.Message);
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                },
                ProtocolValidator = new OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator(),

                TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true
                }
            });
```

Comment: OpenIdConnect is not really responsible for the sessions. Could you show how you are configuring CookieAuthentication and Sessions?

Comment: // Configure Cookie-based Authentication
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions() { SlidingExpiration = true });

Comment: Please add it in the question with proper formatting.

Comment: Based on the [Katana](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationOptions.cs), the expired time of cookie should be 14 days by default. When you mentioned **1 hour**, it sounds more like you web app was calling the web API using the access token. Please let me know if I misunderstood.